# Manually logout another user in grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my application I need to programmatically logout a user, not the current one. I was able to expire its session but this does not force a logout for that specific user. So my question is, how can I force a logout on the user's next request? This is my code now:

```
sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().each {
   principal = it
   sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(it, false).each {
       if (principal.username == userSec.username) {
           it.expireNow()
       }
   }
}
```

I have this in my resources.groovy:

```
sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)
    sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
        maximumSessions = -1
    }
    concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){
        sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
        expiredUrl = '/login/concurrentSession'
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the session mechanismus it is not possible. You have to use a storage medium where you can keep the users. This medium can be either an in-RAM singleton, like `ConcurrentHashMap` instance, or a DB, depending on your clustering architecture.

Then upon each call to `springSecurityService.currentUser` (e.g. in Spring Security core plugin), you have to check if the `sessionRegistry` contains that user, and if not, invalidate the session or the user