# Grails logout another logged in user

Tags: grails, spring-security, logout

I have grails application and installed spring security core plugin. I want to logout another logged in user.
I am able to get all logged in users list using sessionFactory.

Help needed.

Please give me detailed explanation.

I followed this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838437/manually-logout-another-user-in-grails) but, I am not able to logout by just simply invalidating session.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidation should work.
This code is 100% working on grails 2.3.5, spring-security-core:2.0.0

```
    def sessions = ContextListener.instance().getSessions()
    def sessionToInvalidate = sessions.find{it.id == someId}
    sessionToInvalidate.invalidate()
```

Update: ContextListener is not standart class. However, it's easy to implement. You can see how it's implemented in **App info grails plugin** [here](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-app-info/blob/master/src/java/com/burtbeckwith/grails/plugins/appinfo/ContextListener.java)

Comment: As I commented at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461557/how-to-get-httpsession-from-sessionid-in-grails-application without the implementation of `ContextListener` this is not a useful answer

Comment: sessionToInvalidate.invalidate() doesn't logout user. So I used sessionToInvalidate.setMaxInactiveInterval(1)

Answer (score 0):

@Taras and @Burt
Thanks

I followed as both of you suggested in this answer. Working fine.

But invalidate mothod doesn't invalidate session and another user keeps on using application. I don't know why this weird behavior.

So I used `sessionToInvalidate.setMaxInactiveInterval(1)`. And this works as I expected.