# How to get HttpSession from sessionId in grails application

Tags: grails, spring-security, sessionid, httpsession

I have grails application, using sessionRegistry I can get sessionId.

Now, how can I get HttpSession from that sessionId.

Comment: By 'sessionFactory' you mean the Hibernate SessionFactory? That has nothing to do with HTTP sessions, the names are just coincidentally similar. The 'session' concept is used in various places, e.g. JMS and others. They're not related and don't share ids.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `HttpSession` then how about this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap

@Component
class SessionTracker implements HttpSessionListener, ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final ConcurrentMap<String, HttpSession> sessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpSession>();

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        def servletContext = ((WebApplicationContext) applicationContext).getServletContext()
        servletContext.addListener(this);
    }

    void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        sessions.putAt(httpSessionEvent.session.id, httpSessionEvent.session)
    }

    void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        sessions.remove(httpSessionEvent.session.id)
    }

    HttpSession getSessionById(id) {
        sessions.get(id)
    }
}
```

Once you drop this into src/groovy it should be automatically available in your Spring context. You can use it like this after injecting into a controller or service.

```
sessionTracker.getSessionById('sessionId')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
def sessions = ContextListener.instance().getSessions()
def sessionToInvalidate = sessions.find{it.id == sessionId}
```

Update:
as Burt Beckwith mentioned, `ContextListener` is not standart class. However, it's easy to implement. You can see how it's implemented in **App info grails plugin** [here](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-app-info/blob/master/src/java/com/burtbeckwith/grails/plugins/appinfo/ContextListener.java)

Comment: `ContextListener` is not a standard class, it must be something that you're using in an app that's registered in web.xml as a listener to keep track of sessions. Without that class source, this answer is not useful at all.